# How to return the result of multiple promises in an express route?

Tags: node.js, express

Below is a route to retrieve information for my user's dashboard. I'm trying to avoid nesting all the promises (i hear its called callback hell) and still get the correct outcome. I'm assuming the code snippet below doesn't return anything because at run time it's blowing past all the promises and simply returning the three empty arrays before the promises have a chance to resolve. I tried to use async/await with no success and am not sure if that's even what I need. In this given situation what is the best practice for handling these promises and returning all the results all at once?

```js
// @route  GET api/user/dashboard
// @desc Retrieve all of the user's dashboard info
// @access Private
router.get("/dashboard",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const donations = [];
    const events = [];
    const teams = [];

    req.user.donations.forEach(donation_id => {
      Donation.findOne({ _id: donation_id })
        .then(donation => {
          if (donation) {
            donations.push(donation);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });

    req.user.events.forEach(event_id => {
      Event.findOne({ _id: event_id })
        .then(event => {
          if (event) {
            events.push(event);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });

    req.user.teams.forEach(team_id => {
      Team.findOne({ _id: team_id })
        .then(team => {
          if (team) {
            teams.push(team);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });

    return res.status(200).json({ data: { donations, events, teams } });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` to wait for all of the `Promises` to resolve first. You'll need to map each `donation` (and `event`, and `team`) to a `Promise` so you can call `Promise.all` on each group of `Promise`s, and then you need to call `Promise.all` on those three groups.

Because the `donations`, `events`, and `teams` all need something similar (extract the `_id` property from an array, call `.findOne` with that `_id`, and filter all results), it would be good to abstract that all away into a single function, to keep your code DRY:

```
const getItems = async (arr, finder) => {
  const foundItems = await Promise.all(
    arr.map(({ _id }) => finder.findOne({ _id }))
  );
  return foundItems.filter(Boolean);
};

async (req, res) => {
  const [donations, events, teams] = await Promise.all([
    getItems(req.user.donations, Donation),
    getItems(req.user.events, Event),
    getItems(req.user.teams, Team),
  ])
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  return res.status(200).json({ data: { donations, events, teams } });
};
```

Without `async` and `await`:

```
const getItems = (arr, finder) => (
  Promise.all(
    arr.map(({ _id }) => finder.findOne({ _id }))
  )
  .then((foundItems) => foundItems.filter(Boolean))
);

(req, res) => {
  Promise.all([
    getItems(req.user.donations, Donation),
    getItems(req.user.events, Event),
    getItems(req.user.teams, Team),
  ])
    .then(([donations, events, teams]) => {
      res.status(200).json({ data: { donations, events, teams } });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: thank you man, that's very detailed. Do i need to be running a specific version of node to resolve  `async (req, res) => {` ? I attempted that before and the interpreter complains.

Comment: I believe you need to have Node 7.6+ to use `await`. `await` makes the program flow easier to understand, but it's not essential, See edit for the code without `async`/`await`